# Equiangular Triangle with length of rows are odd

Tags: python-3.x

sample_output
  *
 ***
*****
None

## Why is there "None"

sample_input = 5

def tri_wave(sample_input): 
    row = sample_input - (sample_input - 1)//2 
    for i in range(0,row + 1): 
        a = i + (i - 1) 
        sample_outputMA = int((sample_input - a)/2) * " " + (a * "*") + int((sample_input - a)/2) * " "
    print(sample_outputMA) 
print(tri_wave(sample_input))

Comment: Because your function doesn't return anything, but you're printing its output. Also please note https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help - you should use code blocks, not endless `&nbsp;` and `<br>`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is there `None`

You defined a function that lacks a [`return`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) statement.
By default your function will return `None` after executing its final statement.
The [REPL](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/repl/) displays the function's return value.